# How can I import Ethereum Account(s) into my own DApp? - iOS

Tags: web3js, wallets, contract-invocation, dapp-development

I'm currently building an **iOS** Ethereum DApp/Wallet, and my biggest challenge so far has been finding information about how to import Accounts from the Ethereum Network into my DApp.

When I look at Mist for example, I can scan a *QR Code* of a given account's address, and that of course will allow me to get the Account's **address** into my iOS DApp, but what about the private key? (or the account's password?)

My iOS client communicates with a Node.js Server, which in turn performs the calls to my deployed Contract(s) via Web3.js, but in order to call state-changing functions I need the account's password to unlock it first. So, in this scenario, Do I need to ask the user the account's password for each Transaction? (Just like MIST does) Or... am I supposed to use the **Private Key** in this case? and If so, How can I import it?

As you can tell, I'm very confused about the *importing* procedures in general.

Note. For this Scenario assume I can send password(s) to my Node.js server securely, encrypted, etc.